# Adding User input without rounding (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, addition, rounding, google-apps-script

I am adding a users input in to UI as they add numbers and returning the results.  The input is currency so I need to carry it out two decimals and not round.

Here is an example of my code:

```
    function ceiling2(number) {
  var ceiling2;
  return ceiling2 = Math.ceil(number*100)/100;
}
//Totals
function lD23Total (e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var tB1v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox1);
  var tB9v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox9);
  var tB17v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox17);
  var tB25v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox25);
  var tB33v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox33);
  var tB41v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox41);
  var tB49v = parseInt(e.parameter.TextBox49);
  var lD23 = app.getElementById("LabelD23").setStyleAttribute('fontWeight','bold');
  var lD23T = tB1v + tB9v + tB17v + tB25v + tB33v + tB41v + tB49v;
  lD23.setText("$ " + ceiling2(lD23T));

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;  
}
```

Currently it returns a rounded number.

I appreciate an suggestions you may offer!

Jon

Answer (score 0):

The function parseInt() will convert the value to an integer, dropping the values after the decimal. Use parseFloat() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is just fine... 
if you remove the parseInt() and replace it either with parseFloat()as suggested by Eric or by Number() it should work... 
if not then the problem might come from the way numbers are written:

If you used 26,4567 but you should use 26.4567  with a dot as separator in place of a comma.

Could you try and keep us informed ?
regards,
Serge

Or you can use this before sending to your function:

```
var newnumber=Number(number.toString().replace(",","."));// convert to string, replace comma with dot and set as number again.
```

and your function will work in both cases